# How to abort a file download in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, http, jakarta-ee

We have a file download link that is initiated by setting the location.href in javascript to a servlet.  The servlet will most likely download a file, but under some conditions, we want to abort it.  I returned a 304 http status code which seems to work except for one wrinkle - the page's onunload fires.  Is there something I can do from that server side to tell the page that it's not unloading and to just chill out?

Comment: Is it the servlet that downloads the file, or the client?

Comment: Client initiates via a link, but the servlet has the rules about whether the file comes back or not.